# Change value of dropdown to null if specific change is made to radio button, but not just any change

Tags: javascript, forms

Here's a code that will change a dropdown menu with the ID of "106" to a null value if I change a radio button with the ID of "101" from one option to another:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('input[name="item_meta[101]"]').change(function(){
    $('select[name="item_meta[106]"]').val('');
  })
})
</script>
```

I need, however, to make 106 change to null ***only if*** a specific value in 101 is selected, but not just any available values. The values of the radio button id=101 are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 respectively. So I want 106 to revert to null value if, say, 101 is changed from 5 to 4, but not from 5 to 3.

Is this possible? If so, it would obviously involved changing the ".change(function()" to some other param, but I don't know what it would be.

Thanks any advance for any help. Here's a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3N2TT/

UPDATE: Here's the final code that worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('input[type="radio"][name="item_meta[101]"]').change(

function () {
    var valCheck = this.value === '4 Categories - $90';
    $('select[name="item_meta[106]"]').val(function () {
        return valCheck ? 'null' : this.value;
    });
});
})
</script>
```

Thanks, David!

Comment: When you're asking questions about JavaScript it *really* helps to post your (relevant) HTML; and to post a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/). Help *us* to help *you*, and you get better/faster responses.

Comment: No problem, but the reason I linked you to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) (and again...) is because on your site we have to look through *all* your HTML and *all* your JavaScript. Plus we can only edit/change through the developer tools of the browser. If you use JS Fiddle (or other, similar, sites) we can see, and edit, the code in place and reload those changes, incrementally improving/experimenting. Also, with code demonstrations, please remember: [Short, Self-Contained, Correct/Compilable Example(s): 'SSCCE'](http://sscce.org/), which makes it easier for us to help.

Comment: OIC. OK, I'll give it a shot. I've never used JS Fiddle before. Give me a minute.

Comment: Sorry it took so long. I think I've got the relevant bits up:

http://jsfiddle.net/g6P2V/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own take on your problem is the following:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="item_meta[101]"]').change(
    function(){
        // testing if the chosen value is equal to '4' (all input values are strings):
        var valCheck = this.value === '4';

        // setting the value of the select:
        $('select[name="item_meta[106]"]').val(function(){
            /* setting to 'null' if the valCheck evaluates to true, otherwise returning
               the currently-selected value: */
            return valCheck ? 'null' : this.value;
        });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nxqnK/).

References:

- [Attribute-equals `[attribute="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Thanks, David. I feel like yours is really close but I can't get it to work yet. Still trying.

Comment: "[Can't] get it to work" suggests that something is going wrong. What is it *not* doing that it should (or what is it doing that it shouldn't)? Are there any errors reported in the developer console? What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Thanks, David. I just sent you an email with a link to the form I'm working with. (I hope that's not bad form here.) "Not working" means the dropdown isn't clearing after changing the radio button. I'll check for errors.

Comment: I've tried 'null' and I've also tried attempting to revert it to its default selection 'Select your 5th category number' but neither have worked yet.

Comment: Note that I left a syntax error in the originally posted code, I started a multi-line comment with `//` and then closed it on the following line with `*/`, which is invalid and may (unless you caught it yourself and corrected) have been the source of the problem.

Comment: I did catch that, after two attempts with it. Thanks though. Still not clearing the dropdown, even though it works perfectly in your JS Fiddle.

Comment: Great, now you need to *add jQuery* (so that `$ is [not] undefined`, check the console). Add in your `frmCheckDependant()` function (again: check the console; or simply remove the `onclick` event-handler (and why are using `onclick` when you've got jQuery?)). And generally tidy it up so that we're addressing *only* a minimal/sscce demo.

Comment: The code found in the HTML section is generated by Formidable Pro, a plugin. I didn't write it. The jquery code I posted in my original question is taken and modified from Formidable Pro's forum, but they don't provide help with custom jquery. I didn't write that either. I'm just a guy trying to make it work. I appreciate your patience. I've added jquery to the JS Fiddle, but I don't know how to add in my frmCheckDependant() function.

Comment: Now the script is working in my JS fiddle, but I don't know what I did to make it work. It wasn't a script change.

Comment: To clarify, it is working in my JS Fiddle, but not on the actual website. The header includes jquery 1.8.3 and that version works on the JS Fiddle. I'm baffled.

Comment: I've tidied it up by removing all dropdowns except 106. It is still working in the Fiddle, but not on the site. I'm at a loss.

Comment: I finally got it working. Thanks for your patience with me. It came down to a syntax error. facepalm

Comment: I've updated the final working code in the original question.

Comment: Could you please help to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595547/convert-dropdown-to-selection-boxes-with-color

Answer (score 0):

Use click function and use class as the radio box selector.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $('.myradiobox').click(function(){
    var radioVal = this.val();
    if(radioVal == 5 || radioVal == 4)
    {
       radioVal == 'NULL';
    }
    $('select[name="item_meta[106]"]').val(radioVal);
  })
})
```